# Php Redis add values in Sets without sorting

Tags: php, redis

I am trying to build a **Sitemap Generator** for my website and therefore trying to collect links from my website and then looping through these links to collect more links found. For e.g:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

$redis->sAdd('myLinks', 'www.example.com');
$redis->sAdd('myLinks', 'www.example.com/1');
$redis->sAdd('myLinks', 'www.example.com/2');
$redis->sAdd('myLinks', 'www.example.com/3');
...
```

But when I check my set

```
print_r($redis->smembers('myLinks'));
```

It doesn't maintain the values in there adding manner. The output of the code is

```
Array
(
  [0] => www.example.com/7
  [1] => www.example.com
  [2] => www.example.com/2
  [3] => www.example.com/5
  [4] => www.example.com/1
  [5] => www.example.com/4
  [6] => www.example.com/3
  [7] => www.example.com/8
  [8] => www.example.com/9
  [9] => www.example.com/6
  [10] => www.example.com/10
)
```

I want to know if there is any way to maintain the position of the values the manner they were added like in above example from 0 to 10?

I don't want to move to Redis List because they are really slow when it comes to iteration through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with a `Sorted Set`. Each time, when you need to add a link, add it to the `Sorted Set` with the size of the set as score (`ZCARD`).

```
ZCARD mylinks
ZADD mylinks result_of_zcard link
```

In this way, you can keep these links sorted. In order to make these operations atomic, you can wrap these two commands into a Lua script.

When you want to get these links in the order that you added, just use `ZRANGE mylinks 0 -1`.

If you need to iterate these links, you can use either `ZSCAN` or `ZRANGE`. Both commands are fast, i.e. `O(1)` and `O(logN)`.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your kind response. Please can you elaborate how can I use ZSCAN or ZRANGE for itereting in PHP because I could not find any result on these two when it comes to PHP.

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow To get the first element: `$redis->zRange('mylinks', 0, 0);`. To get the second: `$redis->zRange('mylinks', 1, 1);`, and so on. For details on `zScan` and `zRange` check the github link of [phpredis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis)